# Finding the minimum and maximum of a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, max, min

Let's say I have 2 arrays inside a single array, like:

```
main_array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

I would like to find the `min` and `max` of each of those arrays and store them in a single array. For the above it would be:

```
result = [1, 4, 4, 7]
```

How do I use Python's inbuilt `min()` and `max()` in this case?

I tried `min(main_array)` and `max(main_array)` but that is giving me:

```
result = [1,7]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: show what you have done

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use `min()` or `max()` on single list to get it's min/max value. You can also use list comprehension to loop through lists in list and functions you want to use:

```
main_array = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7]]    
res = [func(l) for l in main_array for func in (min, max)]    
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
main_array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
result = []

for inner_list in main_array:
    result.append(min(inner_list))
    result.append(max(inner_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the more readable way to do it is:

```
result = []
for list in main_array:
    result.append(min(list))
    result.append(max(list))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
main_array = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]

out = []
for arr in main_array:
    out.extend([min(arr), max(arr)])

print(out)
```

You need to iterate over each of the sub arrays and call `min` and `max` on that.

You could also use generators

```
def minthenmax(arr):
    for i in arr:
        yield min(i)
        yield max(i)

print(list(minthenmax(main_array)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to search for min and max on each item of lst.
    lst =  [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]
    m = []
    for k in lst: m.append([min(k), max(k)])
    => [[1, 4], [4, 7]]

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.

Answer (score 0):

First off you're missing a common on the definition of your main array...

```
 main_array = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]
```

To get the min of the first sub-array.

```
min(main_array[0])
```

...and the max...

```
max(main_array[0])
```

Hopefully you can work out the rest from this.

Answer (score 0):

In one line. You can use build-in map function to map two inner lists to `min` function and then `max` function. Finally you can concatenate them.

`map(min, main_array) + map(max, main_array)`

Answer (score 0):

```
main_array = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]
x = min(main_array[0]), max(main_array[0])
y = min(main_array[1]), max(main_array[1])
new_array = [i for i in x + y]
print (new_array)
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 4, 7]
```